# How can I get the country codes of a d3js.org/world-50m.v1. map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

In my data I have a column ***"CountryCode"*** with values like "US", "DE", etc.

How can I color for example all countries that have traded the animal "Iguana" (Column: Genus)?
From my point of understanding, I should compare the country codes of the map with the country codes of my data and then highlight all countries with a different color, that have traded with "Iguana". Therefore I should get the country codes of the d3 world map.

This is my code so far:

```
const map = svg.append("g").attr("class", "map");

// create projection
const projection = d3.geoMercator();

// create path generator
const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

d3.csv("./data/wild-life-trade-live.csv").then(function(data) {
// load data and render map
const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }))
    .interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);
    
    d3.json("https://d3js.org/world-50m.v1.json").then(function(world) {
        // create map features
        map.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", "lightgray")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .on("mouseover", function() {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", "#D7B895");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", "lightgray");
        })
        });
        
        const buttons = d3.select(".section-4")
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "button-container")
            .selectAll("button")
            .data(["Iguana", "Pelicans", "Elephants", "Tigers"])
            .enter()
            .append("button")
            .text(d => d)
            .style("margin-right", "25px")
            .style("margin-left", "25px")
            .style("margin-top", "15px")
            .style("height", "30px")
            .style("width", "188px")
            .on("click", function() {
                const button = d3.select(this);
                const animal = button.text(); // Get the text of the clicked button
                const isClicked = button.classed("selected"); // Check if the button has "selected" class

                // Reset all buttons to default style
                buttons.style("background-color", "#D7B895")
                    .style("color", "black")
                    .classed("selected", false);

                if (!isClicked) {
                    // Apply selected style to clicked button
                    button.style("background-color", "white")
                        .style("color", "black")
                        .classed("selected", true);

                    // Update fill color of countries based on animal
                    map.selectAll("path")
                    .attr("fill", function(d) {
                        const countries = data.filter(function(row) {
                            return row.Genus.toLowerCase() === animal.toLowerCase() && 
                                (row.Importer === d.properties.id || row.Exporter === d.properties.id); //this doesn't work!
                        }).map(function(row) {
                            return row.CountryCode;
                        });
                
                        if (countries.length > 0) {
                            if (countries.includes(d.properties.id)) {
                                return "#D7B895";
                            } else {
                                return "lightgray";
                            }
                        } else {
                            return "lightgray";
                        }
                });
                svg.transition();
        }});`
```

I tried this:

```
const countries = data.filter(function(row) {
      return row.Genus.toLowerCase() === animal.toLowerCase() && 
         (row.Importer === d.properties.id || row.Exporter === d.properties.id);
```

But this doesn't work because `d.properties.id` is undefined. I need to somehow get the country codes of this map.

Answer (score 0):

The countries in your [map data file](https://d3js.org/world-50m.v1.json) have no properties and just a single numeric id. You'll need some map data that does have properties that align well with your CSV data. You could probably find what you're looking for [on Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/), though you'd need to convert those shapefiles to TopoJSON.

I did that using [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) and, together with a simplified version of [this file available on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/cites/cites-wildlife-trade-database), I generated [this map](https://observablehq.com/d/359df5572cbf13ac) of countries that "Import" iguanas (whatever that means).  [Here's the map data file](https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/8beb0d1d124e23a7d09f74a575565d1bebf49a11b22c64587f9bf1202e6b5a597bb264ff8eb6e223441075d28640bea6250caa3cf9944b698000a91d05143a76).

[image]